# Not able to login to Artifactory docker registry

Tags: artifactory

Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://artifactory.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found.
I am able to login through UI, but not form command line. I have admin privilege. What could be the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

2 things to check first, what is the [docker access method](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry) (Check this under Artifactory UI --> Settings | [HTTP Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings#HTTPSettings-DockerReverseProxySettings)) you are using and any reverse proxy on top of the Artifactory.

Looking over the error, "artifactory.com" is being used, so I assume it is the repository path method, so first fix the HTTP settings and change the docker access method to the repository path.